# Execute string in JS from php file, setTimeout vs eval()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I have a Javascript code that uses ajax to get a response from .php file. I was using "eval()" for test and everything was working fine (a little slow) but I found out a nice trick that I can use setTimeut. I am still a beginner but everyone says that eval is dangerous and I should avoid it thats why I was looking for an alternative. setTimeut works much better than eval (speed) but is it safe?

So is it safe to use setTimeout(result, 0) to execute that code that I recieve from php file (as string)? Or is it safer than eval()? Please help, thanks in advance.

My code Javascript:

```
    function sendAjax(vData) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '_process.php',
        data: vData,
        success : function (result) {
            setTimeout(result, 0);
            //old method eval(result);
        }
    });
}

$('.button1, .button2, .button3').click(function () {
    sendAjax($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

and .php file

```
if (isset($_GET['button1'])) {
echo    " $('.button1').hide(500, function () {
                console.log('some1clickedbutton1');

            });";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Does that work? I've never tried either Eval() or setTimeout to run a function returned from ajax. But it makes more sense to me to have the function already on in the javascript and simply call it based on the value returned.

php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['button1'])) {
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

then the javascript:

```
 function sendAjax(vData) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '_process.php',
        data: vData,
        success : function (result) {
            if(result == "true"){
                hideButton1();
            }
        }
    });
}

function hideButton1(){
    $('.button1').hide(500, function () {
                console.log('some1clickedbutton1');
            });
}

$('.button1, .button2, .button3').click(function () {
    sendAjax($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, both ways eval(result) and setTimeout(result, 0) works. Eval is slow and like everyone says "evil" but I have no idea what about setTimeout.

yeah thank you for your help but I want to hide some javascript code in .php file (I am just playing with js and php files) and I don't want to keep few functions in .js code that's why I am using ajax for it :)

Answer (score 0):

A rose by any another name…

Most of the problems with `eval` are general problems with taking strings and executing them as code. Avoid passing strings to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, `new Function()` and anything else along those lines.

In general, you are better off writing your code in actual JavaScript and then sending plain data (with no logic in it) back from the server.

Making lots of assumptions about what you code is trying to do, you could do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['button1'])) {
    $clicked = "button1";
}

$response = array( clicked => $clicked );
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo encode_json($response);
```

and

```
success : function (result) {
    $("." + result.clicked).hide(500, function () {
        console.log("some1clicked" + result.clicked);
    });
}
```

Comment: hide() was an example, I want to keep few functions in the .php that will be called through ajax and executed (by setTimeout) from a response. I just want to hide some JS code in PHP code and run them when I need to. (just for test if it is possible)

Comment: You can't *hide* the JS in the PHP. You still have to send it to the client in order for it to execute, and then it isn't hidden any more. All you are doing is making things less efficient and more complicated (and thus harder to maintain and debug).

Comment: Yes I know that, code won't be hidden anymore when executed. But I want to do this anyway. 'hidden' functions in php won't be complicated, just few lines but not1 will see them unless they execute them through the button, right? The question; is setTimeout better than eval() in this case?  I mean is there any "security" danger?